# window wsl subsystem(ubuntu) Yarn download dependency error

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/home/posu2022/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-@babel-compat-data-7.13.15-7e8eea42d0b64fda2b375b22d06c605222e848f4/node_modules/@babel/compat-data/LICENSE' -> '/mnt/d/workSpace/itvdsit-vdp-web/it-vdp-web/node_modules/@babel/compat-data/LICENSE'".